# Prove $ \operatorname{im}( \phi ) \cong G/\ker( \phi)$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, proof-writing

The book on abstract algebra that I'm reading uses the fact that, given the groups $G$ and $G'$ and a homomorphism $\phi:G \rightarrow G'$, then

$$ \operatorname{im}( \phi ) \cong G/\ker( \phi )$$

However the author doesn't provide a proof and simply states that it follows from "standard group theory". How could one prove the theorem above?

---

I would appreciate any help/thoughts!

Comment: This is the [first isomorphism theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Isomorphism_theorems#First_isomorphism_theorem) and its proof is contained in virtually every elementary abstract algebra textbook.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a roadmap for the proof, which appears in all books:

Define $\pi : G/\ker( \phi ) \to \operatorname{im}( \phi )$ by $\pi(x \bmod \ker \phi) = \phi(x)$. Then prove:

- $\pi$ is well defined
- $\pi$ is a group homomorphism
- $\pi$ is injective
- $\pi$ is surjective